# Removing click event popup from clusters in arcgis

Tags: javascript, jquery, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am very much new to arcgis & trying to remove cluster info window which is shown when user clicks cluster.

Here is link to [Demo](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering)

Also I do not want to show individual points which shown when user clicks cluster. Instead I want to show my own info window which will be cluster specific & not point specific.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Do you want this type of feature ?

Comment: I managed to remove onClick evet from its javascript. Now I am trying to add my functionlity for onhover event.